# Why do we need "The" here?

Tags: word-usage

**The** logging industry

The defense of **the** forest

Those are my mistakes in a recent essay. Although I've got the correction for them, I still don't really understand the way it works. I suppose "The"s are needed there because I was talking about specific, familiar things? And most of the time I use "the" just based on my instinct, like whether it sounds natural or not. I really lack a comprehensive understanding of it.

Comment: Do you mean that you were marked down for NOT using "the" or for using it?  What are the full contexts of the usages?

Comment: Yes, I was marked down for not using "the". Here are the contexts:

"Each individual can contribute to the defense of forest even if you are just a primary student."

"Particularly, logging industry has seen a remarkable increase in extent."

Comment: As I read that sentence from left to right, the first thing that happens is that I think, "I would say *In particular*; I wonder if technically *Particularly* is acceptable here?"  I'm 90% certain it isn't.  Next, I see *logging industry*.  Not having any context to tell me otherwise, I think that *logging* is a gerund having to do with making notes in a log.  Then I think *industry is going to modify the word I think I am about to find, which will be the object of* logging.

Comment: "We have been talking about environmental issues for decades. And it seems that more and more problems would arise as the world is constantly changing. Particularly, **the** logging industry has seen a remarkable increase in extent. For me, people need to take action and join hands on solving this regardless of who they are, and this must be done extensively, not just within the government and environmental organisations." Is it better now? For logging industry, I meant the industry of cutting down trees for commercial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When refering to an industry as a while, it is usual to use the definite article "the"

> - The automotive industry
> - The computer industry

The original sentence:

> Particularly, logging industry has seen a remarkable increase in extent.

should have a definite article. Not only for industries, but where a general thing is the subject of a sentence, a definite article is usual.

> - The sea is a stern mistress.
> - The dessert is a place of extremes.
> - The notion of universal human rights developed gradually.
> - The forresat can be a place of calm.

The original sentence

> "Each individual can contribute to the defense of forest

should have a definite article on "forest".

> "Each individual can contribute to the defense of the forest.

Here again 'forest is begin used to mean all forests, or forests in general. in English this is indicated by use of the definite article.

---

By the way, the connection between "logging" meaning "cutting down trees" and "logging" meaning "recording events in a document" is an interesting one. The original meaning of "log" is "piece of wood". But it was once common for a ship to measure its speed through the water by throwing a piece of wood tied to a line into the water, and measuring how far it went in a fixed amount of time. This was called "throwing the log" or "taking a log". It was usual to record these measurements on a regular basis, and this record become known as simply "a log" or "the log". From this the more general record of events on board ship came to be known as "the log" or "the captain's log", and by analogy any regular record of individual events, particularly if times or dates are attached to each entry  came to eb known as a log, and keeping such a record as "logging", while "logging" as the thing that a lumberjack or lumber company does uses the original meaning of "log"

Comment: Interesting information! Thanks a lot, @David Siegel! And a very useful explanation, too.

Answer (score 0):

For example I am The Grim Reaper so in that case I am referring to the only one but in other cases, take your example of The forest you were talking about something that was previously said and the audience was familiar with. Idk but I tried.

Comment: Thank you, The Grim Reaper. That makes a lot of sense:D

Comment: No problem. lol